# Universal Image Loader - NullPointerException

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm loading all images in my app using Universal Image Loader.
I'm having a NullReferenceException when loading an image:

```
09-05 09:04:20.376    2704-2737/com.caliatys.mockupbuilder D/ImageLoader﹕ Start display image task [file:///mnt/sdcard/Caliatys.Catalog_ECOGAZ_romania/ECOGAZ SA M2DCn V2.jpg_1024x720]
09-05 09:04:20.376    2704-2737/com.caliatys.mockupbuilder D/ImageLoader﹕ Load image from disk cache [file:///mnt/sdcard/Caliatys.Catalog_ECOGAZ_romania/ECOGAZ SA M2DCn V2.jpg_1024x720]
09-05 09:04:20.376    2704-2737/com.caliatys.mockupbuilder E/ImageLoader﹕ null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ViewScaleType.fromImageView(ViewScaleType.java:59)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.imageaware.ImageViewAware.getScaleType(ImageViewAware.java:105)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.decodeImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:261)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:222)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:135)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

But the strange thing is that in another page, the exact same image is well loaded:

```
09-05 09:05:13.136    2704-2737/com.caliatys.mockupbuilder D/ImageLoader﹕ Start display image task [file:///mnt/sdcard/Caliatys.Catalog_ECOGAZ_romania/ECOGAZ SA M2DCn V2.jpg_1024x720]
09-05 09:05:13.136    2704-2737/com.caliatys.mockupbuilder D/ImageLoader﹕ Load image from disk cache [file:///mnt/sdcard/Caliatys.Catalog_ECOGAZ_romania/ECOGAZ SA M2DCn V2.jpg_1024x720]
```

Any idea why sometimes images are not displayed, with this null exception?

Comment: post your ViewScaleType.java file

Comment: here it is: http://pastebin.com/BF8UnUvH

Comment: 1.9.2 ; I've added UIL using my gradle file: 
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.2'

Comment: no idea? how could I debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue :)

Here is my update to ViewScaleType.java:

```
public static ViewScaleType fromImageView(ImageView imageView) 
{
    if (imageView != null && imageView.getScaleType() != null)
    {
        switch (imageView.getScaleType())
        {
            case FIT_CENTER:
            case FIT_XY:
            case FIT_START:
            case FIT_END:
            case CENTER_INSIDE:
                return FIT_INSIDE;
            case MATRIX:
            case CENTER:
            case CENTER_CROP:
            default:
                return CROP;
        }
    }
    return FIT_INSIDE;
}
```